# rails api and normal application on the same codebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

friends,

need your opnion here please.

I a have already a big rails application, but I need to provide a REST API for other clients like mobile.

My doubt is, it is a rigth choice to use the same codebase, that I already have, to develop my API or I need to create it separeted to the existing application?

The API will work with data that the existing application already have or manipulate.

what cons and pros?

Comment: would create it within. Future will tell you if you need to move. Just create separate controllers

Comment: You should follow API versioning and use existing code with new controllers

Comment: thanks for yours comments. It helps.

why give to me a negative vote? what I did wrong?

Comment: Negative votes were probably because the question was broad rather than specific, and the answer was potentially opinionated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your API in the same app, within a namespace. If you have to ask the question, putting it in the same app is almost certainly the right answer.

Separate apps introduces an extra layer of complexity and you have to deal with stuff like eg. which app is responsible for database migrations? And if your non-API is handling migrations, then how do you ensure your API is up to date with the latest migrations? You'll likely also end up with some code shared between your app and API, which is more difficult if they're in separate apps. So, put them in the one app.

If you haven't built an API in rails before, this is a great starting point: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/surviving-apis-with-rails (well worth the money)